# Creating excel file from asp listview without Interop or library

Tags: asp.net, excel

I am trying to create an excel file based on my asp Listview, but I can't use the Interop since the server does not have the Microsoft suite installed.  I'd also like to avoid using an external library.

Here is part of some code I found on the internet but it doesn't see to work.

```
        public void Export(string fileName, List<string> liste)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader(
            "content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName + ".xls"));
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
                {
                    lvOutput.RenderControl(htw);
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sw.ToString());
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
                }
            }
        }
```

Here's the html item template, it's essentially just a string that I split in 4 columns.

```
<ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-md-3">
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text="<%# Container.DataItem.ToString().Split(';')[0] %>" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-md-3">
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl2" runat="server" Text="<%# Container.DataItem.ToString().Split(';')[1] %>" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-md-3">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%# Container.DataItem.ToString().Split(';')[2] %>" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-md-3">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="<%# Container.DataItem.ToString().Split(';')[3] %>" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I'm assuming the List<string> liste is the ListView data? You're not even writing it to the file you're attempting to make.

Comment: actually that list is the remains of the code I copied I am actually rendering the liview here "lvOutput.RenderControl(htw);"

Comment: what is your ItemTemplate in the ListView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get you the Excel file. I couldn't test RenderControl specifically to your control because you didn't provide a layout. See if this works and update me.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/force-download";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ExcelSheet.xls");
Response.Write("<html xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\">");
Response.Write("<head>");
Response.Write("<META http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">");
Response.Write("<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>");
Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorkbook>");
Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorksheets>");
Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorksheet>");
Response.Write("<x:Name>Report Data</x:Name>");
Response.Write("<x:WorksheetOptions>");
Response.Write("<x:Print>");
Response.Write("<x:ValidPrinterInfo/>");
Response.Write("</x:Print>");
Response.Write("</x:WorksheetOptions>");
Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorksheet>");
Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorksheets>");
Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorkbook>");
Response.Write("</xml>");
Response.Write("<![endif]--> ");
Response.Write(sw.ToString()); //insert html string
Response.Write("</head>");
Response.Flush();
```

[Source](http://forums.asp.net/post/3947345.aspx)

**EDIT**: Also.. the excel file should load just fine, but if you get format error in Microsoft Excel, you will want to first check your control rendering and make sure the html string is correct.

Comment: I have updated the question with my template info, I'll try your method and let you know asap how if it worked out, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I understand you would like to avoid using an external library, but in fact, your code is not producing an Excel file. You're just sending HTML to the browser with a specific content-type, in the hope that the user will have Excel on his/her machine (which you don't know if they actually do).

You also give up a lot of control over the formatting given that Excel will process the HTML for you.

I would strongly recommend you refrain from doing that, and instead use a library such as [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/) that is widely used and tested by many people...

Comment: Thanks for the answer.